# Popup position based on viewport availability

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I am working on a Netflix/Amazon Prime Video style popup. How would I update the position of the popup based on the availability of the screen. That is, as seen on the image below, when the link is towards the top of the window, the popup gets cut off. Similar thing happens when the primary content is near the bottom/left/right viewport. So I was wondering how detect the edges of the viewport/window and push the popup window up/down dynamically.

Website: https://movie-popup-dinethh.c9users.io/

Issue: [image]

Code: https://github.com/DinethH/Movie-Popup

Comment: `elem.getBoudingClientRect();`

Comment: Could you post some of your code in a jsfiddle or code snippet? My best advice is to use `elem.getBoudingClientRect()` to find the position of the element inside the viewport.

Comment: Thanks. That function helped me to get the job done.

Comment: Wonderful, glad I could help :)